# How to create jupyter notebook with specific python version?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm very new to this.

Here's my problem : I want to create a jupyter notebook that use python 3.7 or above.

I've try to use `virtualenv -p python3` but it's not work for me. Normally, I just use `virtualenv myproject` and I always got "Python 3.6.8" for that jupyter notebook.

PS. when I open my terminal and type `python -V` it's show "Python 2.7.16" but after I start my current jupyter notebook and check the version again it's say "Python 3.6.8". IDK why it's not the same. May be this is the problem also?

Comment: Are you running jupyter notebook directly or are you using anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda then you can open the anaconda terminal and run:

`conda install python=version`

Version is 3.6.8 or whatever you want.

Comment: I'm not using an Anaconda. Is there anyway to do it without anaconda?